# VB6 string functions in C#

Tags: c#, string, vb6

```
If Left(strText, 3) = "De " Then
    Mid(strText, 1, 1) = "d"
ElseIf Left(strText, 4) = "Van " Then
    Mid(strText, 1, 1) = "v"
End If
```

This above VB code needs to be translated into C#.

I know mid and left are

```
strText.Substring(1,1) and strText.Substring(0, 4)
```

but if I can't do

```
strText.Substring(1,1) = "v";
```

Do I need to do..

```
strText.Replace(strText.Substring(1,1), "v"))
```

instead?

There was no comment in the VB6 code. So I am only guessing what is going on here.

**EDIT:** Sorry Wrong version of code

Comment: The first block of code is not `VB6`

Comment: The First Code up there is really worst mixed up between C# and VB

Comment: Without seeing more of the code, it's hard to say but the above code is changing the capital V to a lowercase v - which means it could be simply changing the string to all lowercase.  That can be done with `strText.ToLower();`.

Comment: sorry my minds not in the right place. Replaced the first block with the vb6 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first block of code tests whether the string starts with the characters `Van`, and if it does, it replaces the first character with a `v`.

So the easiest replacement would be:

```
if(strText.StartsWith("De ")) {
   strText = "d" + strText.Substring(1);
}else if(strText.StartsWith("Van ")) {
   strText = "v" + strText.Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: I am going to upvote you after 2 mins.. now I have another question.. if you're interested.

Comment: @user2537701 - if it's just a minor amendment to your existing question, edit it into it. If it is in fact another question, post it as a new question - there's no fee to be paid for how many questions you ask - the only real "don't do this" is opening a new question with essentially the same content as an existing question.

Answer (score 1):

```
strText = "v" + strText.Substring(1)
```

Note that array index starts from 0. I am assuming that you are trying to put "v" at the 1st character position (which is 0) in the string.

EDIT: Note that string in .net is immutable (i.e. the contents of the string can't be modified in place) as compared to VB6 example where you can use `Mid` or `Left` to set a value at a specified character position.

The following will return a new string with modified contents, which should be assiged back to `strText` for you to overwrite the original contents.

`strText.Replace(strText.Substring(1,1), "v"))`

Moreover, this is not a good approach because of 2 things
1) If strText is "van", `strText.Substring(1,1) will return "a"

2) `strText.Replace(strText.Substring(1,1), "v"))` will replace all "a", not just the first.

Comment: compared to VB6 example where you can use Mid or Left to set a value at a specified character position... That's what I was looking for... exactly that!!! Sorry I can't upvote you with this account.

Comment: @user2537701 Odd, you should be able to …

Comment: @user2537701: No problem. Hope the explanation above helps. There is no way you can do that in c# (I don't know if VB.net provides such a thing).